# Data binding in nested custom polymer elements (recursive data-binding)

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, recursive-databinding

I try to bind custom sub elements to values of local storage by using `polymer's` `template repeat` functionality like this:

```
<polymer-element name="aw-outerElement">
<template>
    <template repeat="{{group in grouplist}}">
        <aw-innerElement groupId="{{group.groupId}}" name="{{group.name}}" val="{{group.val}}"></aw-innerElement>
    </template>
</template>
<script>
Polymer('aw-outerElement', {
ready : function () {
    // Binding the project to the data-fields
    this.prj = au.app.prj;
    this.grouplist =  [ 
                    { groupId: 100, name: 'GroupName1', val: this.prj.ke.groupVal100},
                    { groupId: 200, name: 'GroupName2', val: this.prj.ke.groupVal200}

    ];
}
</script>
```

In the code above I try to pass the data binding `this.prj.ke.groupVal100` and `this.prj.ke.groupVal200`
to my inner element `aw-innerElement` through the attribute `val`. The `aw-innerElement` is a custom `paper-input` element where the value attribute should be set to e.g. `this.prj.ke.groupVal100`. It seems that *only* the stored initial value *0* will be set and **NOT** the data-binding string  `this.prj.ke.groupVal100` inside the value attribute. Is there a way to make a data-binding with `template repeat` inside inner elements?

My inner elements looks like this:

```
<polymer-element name="aw-innerElement" attributes="groupId name val">
<template>
    <paper-input type="number" floatingLabel label="{{groupId}} {{name}}" value="{{val}}" error="{{i18nnrerror}}"></paper-input>
</template>
<script>
Polymer('aw-innerElement', {
publish: {
     groupId: 0,
     name: '',
     val: 0
},

ready : function () {
    // Binding the project to the data-fields
    this.prj = au.app.prj;
    ...

}
</script>
```

As you can see above the `value="{{val}}"` of my innerElement should be set to `this.prj.ke.groupVal100` and `this.prj.ke.groupVal200`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm digging up an old question, but for future searchers this might come in handy.
Polymer does not allow a variable as your key, so you need to pull it through a function like so:

```
...
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{users}}">
  <li>{{showValue(item)}}</li>
</template>
...

<script>
  Polymer('aw-outerElement', {
    // Standard Polymer code here
    showValue: function(item){
      return item[myVar];
    }
  });
</script>
```

You can then manipulate as much as you want in `Javascript` and return the output for that one *item* in *items*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new with polymer so maybe my answer is not correct. But I done something like this that you're trying to do.

here is a sample of my code

I guess that your problem is that you didn't use bind on your template

```
<template bind="{{grouplist}}">
    <template repeat="{{group in grouplist}}">
    </template>
</template>


<script>
Polymer('aw-outerElement', {
ready : function () {
    // Binding the project to the data-fields
    this.prj = au.app.prj;
    this.grouplist =  [ 
                    { groupId: 100, name: 'GroupName1', val: this.prj.ke.groupVal100},
                    { groupId: 200, name: 'GroupName2', val: this.prj.ke.groupVal200}
    ];
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing in a value seems to work fine for me in this example: http://jsbin.com/kalih/4/edit

```
<polymer-element name="x-bar">
  <template>
    <paper-input id="input"
                 label="{{name}}"
                 value="{{val}}">
    </paper-input>
    <button on-tap="{{logVal}}">Log val</button>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('x-bar', {
      publish: {
        val: 0
      },
      logVal: function() {
        console.log(this.$.input.value);
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="x-foo">
  <template>
    <template repeat="{{item in items}}">
      <x-bar name="{{item.name}}" val="{{item.val}}"></x-bar>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('x-foo', {
      ready: function() {
        this.items = [
          {
            name: 'baz',
            val: 28
          },
          {
            name: 'qux',
            val: 42
          }
        ];
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>  

<x-foo></x-foo>
```

Btw, your `aw-innerElement` doesn't need to have an `attributes` attribute because you're using the `publish` object (they serve the same purpose, but publish lets you set default values, which you've done). Also, we recommend that you don't camel-case your element names, the HTML parser is actually going to lowercase them all anyway.

Comment: Hi Rob. In your example above you are using a discrete value *val*, e.g. 28! My problem here is that I **DON'T** want to bind a discrete value to my `aw-innerelement` value attribute but I want to do a **variable** data-binding. What I mean is that the `value` attribute of my `aw-innerelement` should be bind to `this.prj.ke.kg100` and should look like this: <aw-innerelement value="**{{this.prj.ke.kg100}}**"></aw-innerelement>. My `groupList` does have 7 groups with 10 sub-groups. My interest is to **NOT** duplicate each `aw-innerelement` according to the account of groups in my groupList.

Comment: What is the value for `this.prj.ke.groupVal100` in your project?

Comment: It's a value stored in local storage of the browser and changable elsewere in my project